# What does 'resist' mean in this IC datasheet?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, datasheet

In the lower right corner on the first page of this datasheet (https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=brief_SG-210STF_en.pdf), the recommended footprint layout shows a hatch pattern with an arrow saying 'resist'.

What does this mean? Is it trying to say 'use a solder mask'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it trying to say 'use a solder mask'?

Yes. They're shortening the term "solder resist", an alternate term for solder mask.